# Python read file - Skip ahead till a specific string found and re-read from previous line

Tags: python, loops

I am having trouble reading from a file and specifying some if/else condition. I will try my best to explain my goal and the issues I am facing. I am working on a XML file of an application and I have parsed the XML into TSV. Now  I have reading through the TSV file and I have go through all the menus, and when I am done with the sub-menu, I have to return to the main menu and go to the next one and keep doing that. Here is a tree view of the application:

```
 1   -> Main Menu   
 2      -> Broadband    
 3          -> Load and Save Profiles   
 4              -> Load Profile 
 5              -> Save Profile 
 6              -> Delete Profile   
 7          -> Interface    
 8              -> xDSL 
 10             -> Ethernet 
 11             -> SHDSL    
 12         -> xDSL Interface   
 13             -> xDSL Mode    
 14             -> MAC Address  
 15             -> Vectoring Mode
 16             -> G.FAST   
 17             -> Auto Re-Sync 
 18             -> Seamless Rate Adaption   
 19             -> G.INP    
 20             -> Power Cut Back   
 21             -> ATM Type 
 22             -> Voip Interface ATM Type
 23             -> Iptv Interface ATM Type  
 24   
 25         -> Ethernet Interface   
 26             -> Autonegotiation  
 27             -> Speed    
 28             -> Duplex Mode  
 29         -> SHDSL Interface  
 30             -> SHDSL Service    
 31             -> Side 
 32             -> Line Mapping 
 33             -> Bonding  
 34             -> Line Parameter
```

This is the original XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ke3600-menu-file language="en" display="English" index="1">
  <version major="0" minor="1" patch="0"/>
  <locale name="en_EN" timezone="CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3"/>
  <menu name="main_menu" display="Main Menu">
    <menu name="broadband" display="Broadband" help="100_help_broadband">
      <onenter proc="activateGfast"/>
      <menu name="load_save_profiles" display="Load and Save Profiles" help="601_help_profiles">
        <application name="load_profiles" display="Load Profile"/>
        <application name="save_profiles" display="Save Profile"/>
        <application name="remove_profiles" display="Delete Profile"/>
      </menu>
      <parameter type="list" name="wanInterface" display="Interface" help="101_help_wanInterface">
        <value id="0" name="ifDSL" display="xDSL"/>
        <value id="1" name="ifSFP" display="SFP"/>
        <value id="2" name="ifETH" display="Ethernet"/>
        <!-- <value i d="3" name="ifWLAN" display="WLAN"/> -->
        <value id="4" name="ifSHDSL" display="SHDSL"/>
      </parameter>

      <menu name="xdslinterface" display="xDSL Interface" help="200_help_xDslInterface">
        <parameter type="list" name="annex" display="xDSL Mode" help="201_help_xdslModi">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_line_annex_a" display="Annex A/M"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_line_annex_b" display="Annex B/J"/>
        </parameter>
        <application name="xdsl_macAddr" display="MAC Address" caption="MAC Address">
          <param type="string" name="xdsl_mac_addr" display="MAC Address" length="25"/>
        </application>
        <parameter type="list" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode" display="Vectoring Mode" help="202_help_Vectoring">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode_disabled" display="Disabled"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode_enabled" display="Enabled"/>
          <value id="2" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode_friendly" display="Friendly"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="xdsl_gfast_mode" display="G.FAST">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_gfast_mode_disabled" display="Disabled"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_gfast_mode_enabled" display="Enabled"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="resync" display="Auto Re-Sync">
          <value id="1" name="re_sync_on" display="On"/>
          <value id="0" name="re_sync_off" display="Off"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="seamlessRateAdaption" display="Seamless Rate Adaption">
          <value id="0" name="sra_off" display="Off"/>
          <value id="1" name="sra_on" display="On"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="xdsl_ginp" display="G.INP">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_ginp_none" display="Off"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_ginp_down" display="Down"/>
          <value id="2" name="xdsl_ginp_up" display="Up"/>
          <value id="3" name="xdsl_ginp_both" display="Down/Up"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="power_cut_back" display="Power Cut Back">
          <value id="0" name="power_cut_back_off" display="Off"/>
          <value id="1" name="power_cut_back_on" display="On"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="atmType" display="ATM Type">
          <value id="0" name="atm_type_aal5" display="AAL5"/>
          <value id="1" name="atm_type_aal0pkt" display="AAL0PKT"/>
          <value id="2" name="atm_type_aal0cell" display="AAL0CELL"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="voip_atmType" display="Voip Interface ATM Type">
          <value id="0" name="voip_atm_type_aal5" display="AAL5"/>
          <value id="1" name="voip_atm_type_aal0pkt" display="AAL0PKT"/>
          <value id="2" name="voip_atm_type_aal0cell" display="AAL0CELL"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="iptv_atmType" display="Iptv Interface ATM Type">
          <value id="0" name="iptv_atm_type_aal5" display="AAL5"/>
          <value id="1" name="iptv_atm_type_aal0pkt" display="AAL0PKT"/>
          <value id="2" name="iptv_atm_type_aal0cell" display="AAL0CELL"/>
        </parameter>
      </menu>

      <menu name="ethernetinterface" display="Ethernet Interface" help="300_help_ethernetInterface">
        <parameter type="list" name="ethInterfaceAuto" display="Autonegotiation">
          <value id="1" name="ethInterfaceAutoOn" display="On"/>
          <value id="0" name="ethInterfaceAutoOff" display="Off"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="ethInterfaceSpeed" display="Speed">
          <value id="2" name="ethIf1000" display="1000MBit/s"/>
          <value id="1" name="ethIf100" display="100MBit/s"/>
          <value id="0" name="ethIf10" display="10MBit/s"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="ethInterfaceDuplexMode" display="Duplex Mode">
          <value id="1" name="ethIfFull" display="Full"/>
          <value id="0" name="ethIfHalf" display="Half"/>
        </parameter>
      </menu>
```

I can go through the menus and submenus and get back to main menu till line 6. After that I am struggling with what to do. The problem is in Line 7, when the user select the `xDSL` type, he should then jump to the menu `xDSL interface` (line 12), then when he is done with all the sub-menus of `xDSL Interface` he should return back to line 10 and select `Ethernet` type and then jump ahead to line 25 and select `Ethernet Interface` and again then when he is done with all the sub-menus of `Ethernet Interface` he should return back to line 11 and select `SHDSL` and do like before.

So this is what I want to do. I am reading the lines from a TSV file and after I read a line and find a specific string for example: `xDSL`, I can start a nested loop inside this loop to check the following lines and go to the `xDSL Interface`, like this:

```
if list_title == "Interface":
                    for inner_record in testData.dataset(findFile("testdata","parsedXML.tsv")):
                        inner_label = testData.field(inner_record,"Label")
                        test.log("Running inner loop.")
                        if inner_label == "xDSL Interface":
                            break
                        else: 
                            inner_label.strip()
if (here is the next if-loop that will work from the line where xDSL Interface was found)
```

Here, `Interface` was found in line 7, and then I am breaking the for loop when `xDSL Interface` is found on line 12, to go to the next if function that will work from line 12. But when it breaks and starts the next if function it resumes from line 8, it doesn't count the line strip I did inside the nested loop in the previous if condition.

Also my next problem would be, when I am done going through all the submenu of `xDSL Interface` till line 23, I want to jump back to line 10 to the `Ethernet` and when this line is found, I want to jump forward to line 25 and continue to `Ethernet Interface` same way like before.

I am keeping a count of the file lines that the code is reading at this moment by the following:

```
for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
```

I can build a list of line start positions (file offsets), and then use `file.seek(line_offsets[n])` to go back to the nth line (counting from zero). But the problem is that I have to keep this `file.seek` inside a if-loop and then continue using another if-loop that is outside this loop. But I face similar problem there, when I skip line or want to go back, in the nested loop it works but how do I continue from an outside if-loop?

My target:

I want to make some nested if loops, where when the file reads `xDSL` type, the IF-statement will search for to the line containing xDSL interface (line 12), then keep reading till all the sub-menus of xDSL Interface, then the if-statement will go back to line 10 and when it founds the string `Ethernet` it will then search for Ethernet Interface and go to line 25  and again then when the read function has gone through all the sub-menus of Ethernet Interface he should return back to line 11 and search for SHDSL and do like before.

If anyone want a short version of the question:

How do I skip ahead reading lines in python using a nested if-loop and then continue reading from that advanced line using an outside loop? Also how do I go back to a previous line in python using a nested if-loop and then continue reading from that previous line using an outside loop?

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example of what you are trying to capture.

Comment: Unless you expect to process huge files, that is hundreds of MB, you are much better off simply reading the whole file as a list of lines (conveniently, that's what python will do if you do `list(f)`) and handling it as such.

Comment: @dawg, I have updated my question. Let me know if you can understand now.

Comment: Have you considered reading through the file and making a) a list of `Interfaces` and b) a separate list for the components of each interface type?

Comment: @spectras, my log file is around 1000 lines long and I already have a OrderedDict in my code. Would you think it would be a good idea to try to read the whole file as lists? Should I look into tuples?

Comment: @Rolf of Saxony, Yes I have considered that. And if can't figure out how to do in this way, I will make a list of interfaces. I was avoiding it till now because I will have more than 100 lists then.

Comment: What did the original XML look like? Maybe use an XML parser that will answer queries against that file rather than parsing and reparsing.

Comment: @dawg, I have attached the original XML with the question.

Comment: @Russo> 1000 lines long is nothing. Now if it was 10 million lines long it would be something to think about. Under that you're just taking the hard path for no reason.

Comment: @spectras, thank you. I will try to read the file as list then and will update the question tomorrow.

Comment: The XML seems straightforward. Can you now craft [XPATH](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) queries that provide the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @dawg, can you please suggest me some good tutorial for XPATH in python? All the tutorial I have found till now is to check out values of a specific children or grandchildren, but I didn't find any (or something related to that) that will iterate through all the nodes, sub-nodes and everything a XML file.

Comment: The ElementTree [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is pretty good. BTW, your XML file snippet is incomplete.

Comment: @dawg, thanks. I just copied a part of the XML file here.

Comment: Now just look at the [Xpath Support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) section. It *looks* to me that that is a simpler approach than what you were trying to do. Best